# Yarn install a only a list of packages (ie not all the project dependencies)

Tags: continuous-integration, yarnpkg

I am trying to launch a script in my project in my CI server (github actions). Since install all my dependencies takes a lot of times, I want to only install a subset of my dependencies.

I have try the following :

```sh
# Bad solution1
yarn install # is not good for me because it install every dependencies = takes time

# Bad solution2
yarn add dependency1 dependency2 # idem

# Poor solution3
rm package.json yarn.lock
yarn add dependency1 dependency2 # would work but I have no garantie of keeping the same versions
```

Is there any way to do this with yarn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this in the past by bundling the script and its dependencies using [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) and committing the file to the repo.

Then you can run the script on the ci without an install using node or yarn.

Here is an example rollup.config.js file. It's for typescript but you should be able to put together something similar if you're using js. You have to install rollup as well as the plugins.

rollup.config.js

```js
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";

module.exports = {
  input: "src/my-script.ts",
  output: {
    file: "lib/my-script.js",
    format: "cjs"
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript({
      typescript: require("typescript"),
      module: "CommonJS"
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs({ extensions: [".js", ".ts"] })
  ]
};
```

Add a script to your package.json and run `yarn build`:

package.json

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c"
  },
...
```

Comment: I have never used rollup before. However, if I understand this script, I will need to install (before executing it) `rollup-plugin-typescript2`, `rollup-plugin-node-resolve`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yeah. I updated the answer and rollup's documentation is [here](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/).